# How do I start background threads when launching a Flask app through gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, gunicorn

I'm launching my Flask app directly through the interpreter.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Thread(target=run_schedule)
    t.start()
    context = ('cert.pem', 'key.pem')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080,debug=False,ssl_context=context)
```

The `run_schedule` function loops forever, unblocking once in a while to do a task.

Apparently I'm supposed to use a wsgi server like gunicorn when I'm not debugging anymore, but it doesn't call the module through `main()`, so the thread doesn't start.

Putting them outside that block won't work because then the thread would get started if any other code imports the module!

`@before_first_request` is almost what I need, but it requires me to poke the server with a request first. Not ideal.

What's the recommended way to do it? (Or do background threads go against wsgi philosophy?)

Comment: You shouldn't spawn background threads in your server application. For example a WSGI server [might spawn several server apps](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#adding-concurrency-and-monitoring) and then you have several background threads. Instead look into [cronjobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [job queues like Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Wanna move it to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't spawn background threads in your server application. For example [a WSGI server might spawn several server apps](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#adding-concurrency-and-monitoring) and then you have several background threads. Instead look into [cronjobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [job queues like Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).